# Centos php 7.1 install svn with pecl

Tags: php, svn, centos, php-7.1

a try install svn for php 7.1 with pecl:

```
pecl install svn
```

and i habe error:

```
pecl/svn requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.1.7
No valid packages found
install failed
```

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error , you need a version less than or equal to php6.0 for the svn package that you are trying to install.
You can try installing a different php version thats suitable for the package or find a working package modified for php 7.1

Look at the official documentation here : 
https://pecl.php.net/package/svn

The dependency is clearly stated to be php 6.0 or older

Answer (score 0):

The current stable released version of PECL svn doesn't work with PHP 7.  There is an open bug report current with a patch submitted to it here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75206

The patch worked for me with PHP 7.1 but it's not been officially vetted and released by the maintainers of PECL svn as of yet.